# Replacing $resource master/copy in $save callback fails to trigger $watch

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular `$resource` along with `angular.copy` to allow the user to reset the form. When the user clicks the save button, I call `$scope.save()` and the `$resource` is saved using `$save()`. Inside the `$save` callback, I replace the master and the model, to reflect the changes made on the backend, while doing so the `$watch` fails to pick up the change, until the user manually edits the form.

Any ideas why?

```
// db.schema is a $resource
var master = db.schema.get(function() {
   $scope.schema = angular.copy(master);
});

$scope.$watch('schema', function() {
   // triggers when $scope.schema is changed
}, true);

$scope.save = function() {
   $scope.schema.$save(function(savedSchema) {
      master = new db.schema(savedSchema);

      // this won't trigger the $watch, but editing the form will
      $scope.schema = angular.copy(master);
   });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your watcher compares for object equality instead of reference (third parameter in `$scope.$watch` method is `true`). Internally Angular does `angular.equals(newValue,oldValue)` instead of `newValue === oldValue`. If you do `var b = angular.copy(a)` then `angular.equals(a,b)` is true (but `a === b` is false).

Also, when you do `$scope.schema.$save` the value of `$scope.schema` gets replaced by the response from the server - I've tried to explain what's happening:

```js
$scope.save = function() {
  $scope.schema.$save(function(savedSchema) {
    //  $scope.schema === savedSchema is now true
    // if you don't want this behavior you could do db.schema.save({},$scope.schema ... instead

    // if the request body equals the response body the watcher will not get called,

    master = new db.schema(savedSchema);
    // master is now a copy of savedSchema
    // angular.equal(savedSchema, master) is true
    // savedSchema === master is false

    // this won't trigger the $watch, but editing the form will
    $scope.schema = angular.copy(master);
    // $scope.schema is now a copy of a copy of itself...
    // $scope.schema === savedSchema is now false
    // angular.equal(savedSchema,$scope.schema) is true
  });
};
```

Comment: Quite helpful, but I still have not gotten it to work. Your first comment "// $scope.schema === savedSchema is now true" is actually not true, if the ajax response differs. I'll open the question again, since I haven't really understood what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure this is true regardless of your response - as long as `isArray` is not true. You can check [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js), it's not many lines. Assuming `obj` is an instance of the $resource `Res`, `obj.$save(success)` is the same as doing `Res.save.call(obj,success)`. See line #449: `var value = this instanceof Resource ? this : ... `, then line #484: ` (success||noop)(value, response.headers);` (first parameter in the success callback function is `value`, and value is the instance that calls $save).